# Earthing and Current flow

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, voltage, conventions

I have been doing problems based on earthing of a circuit but I have never understood as to why earthing(just a single point) doesn't affect the current flow.
I'm confused because if we have a cell whose negative terminal potential is taken as 0 and then earthing also changes the potential of a point to 0 then why is the current flow not affected as the potential has become equal just like how potential is equal along conducting wires? Shouldn't the part of circuit between where it is earthed and the negative terminal of battery get shorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if we have a cell whose negative terminal potential is taken as 0 and then earthing also changes the potential of a point to 0 then why is the current flow not affected as the potential has become equal

You have to use the same reference everywhere for things be consistent.  In a battery powered circuit, we might set the 0V reference to the negative terminal of the battery.

In a wired circuit, we might set the 0V reference to an earth/ground line.

But we can't do both unless they're wired that way.  We can't connect the positive terminal of the battery to an earth wire and declare that both the earth and the negative terminal are 0V.  The potential in this case is *not* equal.

Comment: So, basically it was a mistake about the reference point?

Comment: If you're assuming two different things to be 0V, but they aren't directly connected, then yes.  But feel free to clarify the question if I've misunderstood.

Comment: No, you explained the question really well. I finally understand my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Earthing absolutely can change the current flow! Suppose that we start with this circuit:

[image: Circuit with one earth point]

In that circuit there will be current flowing through resistor B.

Now, suppose that we add an earth as follows:

[image: Circuit with two earth points]

Now, the voltage on both sides of resistor B is the same, so by Ohm's law there is no current flowing through resistor B. So adding the earth most definitely did change the current.

You can consider any separate earth points to be connected by a wire. So the following circuit is equivalent to the two-earth circuit:

[image: Equivalent to two-earth circuit]

This last representation can be more clear than the two-earth representation, but sometimes if you have a complicated circuit with many earth points it can add unnecessary clutter to an already complicated diagram.

Comment: Ok so I get that earthing multiple points can affect the current flow and distribution but then what happens if we earth just a single point? If it doesn't affect current then why do we even do it?

Comment: @DhruvGoel usually it is for safety. The idea being that a person that inserts themselves into the circuit somehow may themselves form a second path to earth.

Comment: But as mentioned in the question why don't we just short everything from the earthed point uptown the negative terminal?

Comment: @Spime that is in fact usually done. We usually have specific wires (often colored green) whose only function is to put a metallic conductor (a short) between every earthed point in a circuit.

Comment: I understand abt the situation when multiples points are earthed but what about when just one is earthed like in your first figure?

Comment: @Spime I don't understand. If just one point is earthed then in what way does it make sense to talk about shorting the earthed points.

Comment: @Spime in the case that a person contacts the hot wire, it's more likely the other end of the person (their feet) will be contacting the physical earth or something connected to it than that they will be contacting the negative terminal of the power feed.

Comment: @Spime Real electrical networks have unintentional "leakage" current paths. If they are driven from high voltage, relative to earth, they can be dangerous. One reason for (apparently) earthing at only one point is to force the potential at that point to be the same as other earthed conductors, for safety.